# SVM for one Vs all acoustic signal classification

Tags: machine-learning, classification, svm

My aim is to classify an impulsive audio signal as whether it is a gunshot or not a gunshot.
I am trying to detect the gunshot event in MATLAB using svmtrain and svmclassify functions. To evaluate the accuracy of classification, the balloon burst and clapping signal are used as different classes. While accuracy of differnetiating between gunshot and either of the two classes is good, the differentiation between gunshot and combined baloon+clap signal is poor.

Please guide how may I use SVM to classify between gunshot and non-gunshot signals?

If SVM is not a good classifier what else may I try to achieve the goal

[image]
[image]

[image]

**Solution-1: Classification after implementing RBF Kernel in svmclassify().**
[image]

**Solution-2: Classification score using predict()**
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply apply non-linear SVM to discriminate between these classes. RBF kernel should do the trick.